# javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

Hi I am experiencing an exception while I am deploying my EJB Module project to my Glassfish Application Server:

It says failed to initialize my Singleton bean "HibernateUtil". The full stack trace is here:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton HibernateUtil
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.checkInit(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:368)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.CMCSingletonContainer._getContext(CMCSingletonContainer.java:116)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2516)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy480.insert(Unknown Source)
    at dao.__EJB31_Generated__CourseDAO__Intf____Bean__.insert(Unknown Source)
    at service.CourseService.insert(CourseService.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 91 more
```

And here is my HibernateUtil bean:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@LocalBean
public class HibernateUtil {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

@PostConstruct
public void buildSessionFactory() {
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties());
    sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
}

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- DataSource properties (begin) -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">testdb</property>

    <!-- JTA transaction properties (begin) -->
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>

     <!--Names the annotated entity class--> 
    <mapping class="entity.Course"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Can anyone tell me if what did i missed on my code. Thanks

Comment: Show us the Hibernate configuration please. And also move your bean code to the question and delete your answer - because it's really not an answer :)

Comment: Hi @PetrMensik thanks by dropping by, i updated my question and included my hibernate config. thanks.

Comment: Hi @PetrMensik theres another issue, it says that class not found on dom4j but i have it already on my library. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing wrong with the initialization of the `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` (e.g. commenting out still throws the same exception), then the following hint may be helpful:

I experienced the same exception after refactoring a large project, and I was 100% sure that there was nothing wrong with the initializer of the `@Singleton` bean.
After copying parts of the project modules bit by bit to a new project, I found out that the reason for the exception was a duplicate naming in the WAR module. Two beans with `@Named` annotation had the same name as value parameter (due to copy paste error). E.g.:

**Bean1:**

```
@Named("duplicateBeanName")
public class Bean1 implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

**Bean2:**

```
@Named("duplicateBeanName")
public class Bean2 implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```